# How to implement oAuth2 on WordPress based website?

Tags: android, wordpress, oauth, oauth-2.0

I own a WordPress based website and trying to write an Android app for it.
I already tried to check out WordPress's open source Android app, but couldn't figure it out.
I want to implement oAuth-2.0 login for the app. Does WordPress have build-in support for oAuth-2.0? How can I implement it on client and server side? Do I need to use a 3rd-party plugin, and is it safe to use plugins?

Answer (score 1):

> Is WordPress has build-in support for oAuth-2.0?

Yes, please refer this link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/

> how can i implement it on client and server side?

For server side, please refer to: https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/

For client side, you can use a well-known library like Retrofit to connect to your server. The link above also provided an examples what client sides should do.

> do i need to use 3rd-party plugin and is it safe to use plugins?

Yes, Wordpress needs a plugin for this. Just pick a well-known plugin and you would be safe.

Comment: Is there free plugin other than  https://wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/ ? its not free (pro version)

Comment: You can refer this link and pick a suitable one: https://www.quora.com/Which-is-the-best-free-WordPress-OAuth-plugin

Comment: no I want to imlement OAuth2 **server** on wordpress the link refers to client side plugins

Comment: @ehsankhormali, you can find a sample of server side inside the link also

Comment: yes just this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/ that is not free and doesn't support password grant type

Comment: yes, what a pity, it was what i used. If you want a free one, you have to google yourself

Answer (score 0):

Your WordPress website needs an OAuth2 server plugin. This is our premium product: https://lana.codes/product/lana-passport/

You can try it with the demo, and there is also detailed documentation for it.

The OAuth2 server plugin provides the authentication server that is connected to the WordPress user system. It also provides the `/authorize`, `/token` and `/resource` endpoints, to which the client can connect and generate a token, and then use the token to access user data. The Android app will need to connect to these endpoints.

Basically, the `Authorization Code` grant type should be used for this purpose, because it also provides the WordPress login interface if you are not logged in and need to identify yourself. This is the most user-friendly and most popular grant type.

But it is possible that in the case of an Android app it is more beneficial to use the `User Credentials` grant type.

It is completely safe to use. We pay a lot of attention to security.

---

However, we also found serious vulnerabilities in several other OAuth plugins:

https://lana.codes/lanavdb/0bab7575-45fc-432d-945e-6100c35c574c/ (CVE-2022-2083)

https://lana.codes/lanavdb/12bb3c02-45f1-4ce8-8a5a-8b44352cf7fc/ (CVE-2022-2133)

https://lana.codes/lanavdb/6d794d65-d44b-4099-94c5-3dd2995b218c/ (CVE-2022-34149)